# Vue Routes does not work properly in production

Tags: vue.js, server, routes, vuejs2, vue-router

I am new to vuejs. For my Vuejs application, I cannot access url like '/foo/apple' in the web hosting server, after I run the "npm run build". It shows error 404 I am using the HTML5 History Mode,(https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) and I implemented the "connect-history-api-fallback" like below in dev-server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')())
```

My router/index.js

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  {
      path: '/Product',
      name: 'Product',
      component: Product,
  },
  {
      path: '/Product/kraftbag',
      name: 'Kraftbag',
      component: Kraftbag
  },
});
```

my website http://americandunnage.n55lwi.info/.
I have looked for a lot of posts regarding to this problem, but I still can find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are likely missing the hashbang (`#`)

try `#/foo/apple` instead of `/foo/apple`

The default setting of the vue router is to use the *hashbang method*. This relies on using the index.html (or whatever defaults to `/` url) page, because everything after it is not taken as part of the url location but passed into the application. For example, in an anchor `<a href="index.html#first-heading">1st heading</a>` this will go to a part of the page, and if you're already on that page, you will not be redirected.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain well. I have updated my code,  I am using the HTML5 history mode.

Comment: can you remove the history mode? if you want to use it, make sure you understand how to set up your server to work correctly, ie. _it becomes a server issue to handle_ so you'll need to provide more info about the server.

Comment: note the 4th paragraph in https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html it states the problem, and the possible server configurations

Comment: Oh, i think I just drop the history mode. It work well now.